# Showing total count for bar chart in c3js tooltip title

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, c3.js

I have a bar chart similar to the one shown in this [link](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar.html).

I wanted to add two features to this bar chart

1. Instead of numbers, I want the tooltip title to display the sum of the count displayed by the bars at the given cordinate.
2. I wanted to display the % in the tooltip instead of the actual count.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by configuring [tooltip.format.title](http://c3js.org/reference.html#tooltip-format-title):

```
   tooltip: {
      format: {
        title: function (index) {
          return totals[index]
        }
```

and [tooltip.format.value](http://c3js.org/reference.html#tooltip-format-value):

```
        value: function (value, ratio, id, index) {
          return d3.format("%")(value / totals[index])
        }
     }
  }
```

And as you can see above, you need to calculate **total values** of your data groups:

```
var totals = [390, 500, 500, 900, 550, 550]
```

**See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/9cyvdktx/1/)**.